# how to integrate smpp to a php website

Tags: php, sms, smpp

I want to integrate a service to my website through SMPP, I have seen some PHP libraries how to setup SMPP connection and so, but I can't find any technical manual for SMPP 3.4 (When I say technical, SMPP syntax ) because I found some but all of them are textual.

NOTE : I have SMPP IP address, username and password, but they didn't provide me any manual of it and they said that it's standard 3.4.

I have tried to setup a connection from a library that I found into github.com and it works, but I can't find a way how to get (read) SMS content from short codes

Comment: You should have a look at this https://packagist.org/packages/php-smpp/php-smpp

Comment: Can you show what you've done to try to get the reading working?

Answer (score 1):

I would not suggest using the PHP library for SMPP, I had a lot of trouble with it. Instead, I would suggest using NodeJS, it is much easier to handle the concurrent running of the script, I also found it also to be much easier to debug.

You can look at the following gist which shows how to read SMS's. https://gist.github.com/Kreshnik/07ed9803165fbdebc237df2de0f8641a